# Nhibernate select all enabled categories with all enabled subcategories and all their enabled subcategories etc

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I wish to create a query in nhibernate to get all enabled categories with their corresponding enabled subcategories and for those subcategories their enabled subcategories etc.

**For this example:**

```
Category A [enabled]
- Subcategory 1 [Enabled]
-- Subsubcategory 1 [Enabled]
--- Subsubsubcategory 1 [Enabled]
-- Subsubcategory 2 [Enabled]
--- Subsubsubcategory 1 [Disabled]
- Subcategory 2 [Disabled]
-- Subsubcategory 1 [Enabled]
Category B [enabled]
```

**the query should return this result:**

```
Category A [enabled]
- Subcategory 1 [Enabled]
-- Subsubcategory 1 [Enabled]
--- Subsubsubcategory 1 [Enabled]
-- Subsubcategory 2 [Enabled]    
Category B [enabled]
```

How do we do this in nhibernate with a Session.QueryOver knowing the correct parent/child mappings are made (parent has a collection of subcategories, a subcategory has also a property with its parentcategory)?

**Edit**

The ugly heavy way to achieve what I want. This however produces a huge load of select queries. How to optimize this?

```
public void GetAllEnabledCategories(){
    var allEnabledCategories = new List<Category>();
            var enabledParentCatgories = Session.QueryOver<Category>().Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null && x.Status==Status.Enabled).List().ToList();

            allEnabledCategories.AddRange(enabledParentCatgories);

            foreach (var category in enabledParentCatgories)
            {
                allEnabledCategories.AddRange(Recursive(category.SubCategories));
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Category> Recursive(IEnumerable<Category> subCategories)
        {
            var allEnabledCategories = new List<Category>();
            var enabledSubCategories = subCategories.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Enabled).ToList();
            allEnabledCategories.AddRange(enabledSubCategories);

            foreach (var category in enabledSubCategories)
            {
                allEnabledCategories.AddRange(Recursive(category.SubCategories));
            }

            return allEnabledCategories;
        }
```

**Edit 2: Implemented solution**

The suggested answer of [Low Flying Pelican](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692085/5740408) works well for me. It results in no more then 2 queries and is for me a good and performant solution. Below a suggested implementation, code can be cleaned and optimized but works.

```
public void GetEnabledCategories()
            CategoryStatusQueryItem result = null;
            Category categoryAlias = null;
            var categoryStatusQueryItemsWithStatusEnabled = Session.QueryOver<Category>(() => categoryAlias).Where(x => x.Status == Status.Enabled)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(() => categoryAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => result.CategoryId)
                    .Select(() => categoryAlias.ParentCategory.Id).WithAlias(() => result.ParentCategoryId)
                    .Select(() => categoryAlias.Status).WithAlias(() => result.CategoryStatus))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<CategoryStatusQueryItem>())
                .List<CategoryStatusQueryItem>().ToList();

            var categoryStatusQueryItemsWithAllParentsEnabled = new List<CategoryStatusQueryItem>();

            categoryStatusQueryItemsWithAllParentsEnabled.AddRange(categoryStatusQueryItemsWithStatusEnabled.Where(x => !x.ParentCategoryId.HasValue).ToList());

            foreach (var source in categoryStatusQueryItemsWithStatusEnabled.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId.HasValue))
            {
                if (AreAllParentsEnabled(categoryStatusQueryItemsWithAllParentsEnabled, source))
                {
                    categoryStatusQueryItemsWithAllParentsEnabled.Add(source);
                }
            }

            var categoriesWithParentsEnabled = new List<Category>();
            var categoryIdsWithAllParentsEnabled =
                categoryStatusQueryItemsWithAllParentsEnabled.Select(x => x.CategoryId).ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < categoryIdsWithAllParentsEnabled.Count; i += 1000)
            {
                var c = categoryIdsWithAllParentsEnabled.Skip(i).Take(1000).ToList();
                var queryResult =
                    Session.QueryOver(()=>categoryAlias)
                        .Where(Restrictions.In("Id",c))
                        .List()
                        .ToList();

                categoriesWithParentsEnabled.AddRange(queryResult);
            }
        }

        public bool AreAllParentsEnabled(List<CategoryStatusQueryItem> categoriesWithStatusEnable,
            CategoryStatusQueryItem category)
        {
            var parentsEnabled = true;
            var parent = categoriesWithStatusEnable.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.CategoryId == category.ParentCategoryId);

            if (parent==null || parent.CategoryStatus == Status.Disabled)
            {
                parentsEnabled = false;
            }
            else if (parent.ParentCategoryId.HasValue)
            {
                parentsEnabled = AreAllParentsEnabled(categoriesWithStatusEnable, parent);
            }

            return parentsEnabled;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to populate a custom DTO from a single query

```
CategoryStatusDTO
{
    int categoryId;
    int parentCategoryId;
    bool parentEnabled;
    bool hasParent;
}
```

Once you load the DTO to the memory, you could do a similar operation you have done on these DTO's and determine list of categories to load, and then use IN operation to load all those categories by Id.

Comment: So basically you are saying: load all categories with status enabled. Then do a recursive loop with logic as used in my question (which results in no extra queries). The result is a list of categories which are enabled and for which all of its parents are enabled. The result should be 2 queries instead of a bunch of queries? Sounds neat.

Comment: Your suggestions works. Added a solution based on this in my question. Thanks!